# command is_executable return false

Tags: php, shell

I have installed the command jpegoptim, and it works  in command line, but when I use the php command is_executable, return false

how can I check if the command can run with php ?, may be is phpini configuration, commands configuration or something like that?

Comment: `if code == 0: print("No Help")`

Answer (score 0):

you would like to check if the command is available for the user php
so it has to be in the PATH, this you can check with e.g. the command `which`. and such you can call from PHP as well

```
<?php

function checkCommand( $command ) {
    $r = shell_exec("which ".$command);
    if ( $r == "" )
        return "ERROR: command not found: ".$command."\n"; 
    else
        return $r;
}

print( checkCommand( "ls" ) );
print( checkCommand( "lsl" ) );

?>
```

beware not creating any remote code execution or path traversal with such stuff. all parameters you might include should be checked very well.